# Java dynamic while expression

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm having some trouble figuring this out. I have a while statement with an expression that should be evaluated on each loop. I feel like I am thinking about this wrong.

What I'm trying to do is loop through the expression `experience >= experienceCap` until it is false. The `experienceCap` is set correctly on each loop, but the `while` expression values never change even though the values actually do change on each loop.

```
public void refreshExperience() {
    int experience = getExperience(); //10
    int experienceCap = getExperienceCap(); //100

    while (experience >= experienceCap) {
            newExperienceCap();
            refreshExperience();
    }

}
```

This results in some log output like:

```
experience: 10
experienceCap: 100
experience: 10
experienceCap: 450
experience: 10
experienceCap: 1120
experience: 10
experienceCap: 2337
```

And an inevitable crash.
I would very much appreciate any input, thank you!

Comment: you need to update the int values in the loop, possibly just return experienceCap when you call newExperienceCap()

Comment: Can you please post the code for ``newExperienceCap()``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop values are not being updated, so it is confusing that in your output it shows *experienceCap* increases. Without seeing all the code i can only guess that the values you are logging are not the ones declared in *refreshExperiece*.

```
public class Test {

    int experience = 10;
    int experienceCap = 100;

    public void refreshExperience() {
        while (experience <= experienceCap) {
            experience = getExperience();
            experienceCap = getExperienceCap();
        }
    }
```

The above code shows *experience* and *experienceCap* being initialized to 10 and 100 respectively. Inside the loop these values are updated with the returned value from *getExperience* and *getExperienceCap* respectively. How you are updating *experience* and *experienceCap* is up to you but this is a simple example:

```
private int getExperience() {
    return experience + 5;
}

private int getExperienceCap() {
    return experienceCap - 10;
}
```

Comment: Yes, so that just sets `experienceCap` to `100` always, right?

To answer your question, in my posted code `newExperienceCap()` sets a  new cap, which is why you see the debug output with a new value. So it sets a new value each loop, but the loop while statement expression is not updated to that new value, and just stays at the first one: `10` thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical `value` vs `reference` problem.
You seem to expect that `int experience` is a reference, but it is not.